# Why is the use of a stack, manipulated by both a stack pointer and a base pointer, the proper solution to handle function frames?

Tags: function, assembly, memory-management, callstack

Can anyone enlighten us from both technical & historical perspective why computers use a stack, manipulated with a stack pointer and a base pointer, with a specific process to follow like saving the return address, pushing the old value of the base pointer, etc...

For more information about the process followed to handle function's call stack check
https://www.learnvulnerabilityresearch.com/stack-frame-function-prologue

My question is: why is it the *proper* solution?

Comment: What are you worried is not "proper" about it?

Comment: @ScottHunter not from criticism perspective , just basic curiosity to fully understand it

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: i only understand the usage when there are non-leaf procedures , so using this abstract idea of stack data structure is logical from human perspective , so the last executed function in procedures call tree will be popped the first and so on , but the philosophy behind the conventions followed like pushing the rbp , return address on x64 System V ABI conventions for example , i want to know the intelligence behind these choices , and why engineers choose this instead of other solutions

Comment: It's not more "proper" than anything else these days, when we have metadata for stack-unwind on exceptions.  In the bad old days, or now with `gcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer` that convention formed a linked-list of frame pointers (each one pointing at the saved EBP of the caller).  See also [x86\_64 : is stack frame pointer almost useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31417784) / [What it means that Ebp register points to the old Ebp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75942196) / [When do we create base pointer in a function - before or after local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47740920)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the proper solution, it is just a common solution.  Using a frame pointer (in addition to a stack pointer) can be seen as simply wasting a register.   One could easily manipulate the stack only as needed.  You could do pushes and pops across the function allowing for some code sequences in a function to have less stack activity and higher performance.

Why would you use a stack frame and worse add a frame pointer?  It is easier to read, easier to debug. It is also easier to construct the function, the compiler will/can have determined the total stack usage for the whole function and can generate function prologue and epilogue based on that knowledge.

May not be useful for x86, but other architectures you can gain a register back if you tell the compiler to not use frame pointers.  Some architectures
or with some compilers that register is not general purpose so the gains may
be smaller.

Because of this habit, some debug tools may rely on the frame pointer for
unwinding functions.  So like building for debug instead of release you are making a bigger slower program to maybe make debug easier.

There is rarely if ever something considered the "proper solution", certainly not in this case, it is a choice.  No one way to do something, no right way to do something.  There are many right ways.  Some may be better in certain use cases than others.  That notion that there can be a right way, and that one popular instance uses some solution leads to others using that solution, without asking why, making it look like it is the only way.  But dad all my friends are going to the party, well if all your friends jumped off the cliff...

x86 is a old architecture both in its age but also its architecture of having 8 bit CISC instructions and not a lot of registers.  Early calling conventions for an architecture like this are stack based, there is a dedicated frame pointer.  As memory gets cheaper and performance gets better and compiled languages come along creating a desire for a function prologue and epilogue, etc, etc, etc.

The folks that were in the offices or meetings at the time over the last several decades are not going to be found on this site, so we cannot get answers as to why specific compilers chose to use a stack frame (for each version).  The best you can hope for here is opinion.

The bottom line though is it is certainly not "the proper solution".  It is simply "a" solution.  Perhaps "a common" solution.  For some architectures with popular compilers like gcc and clang, a frame pointer is not used by default, you have to force it if you want it. (still have a prologue and epilogue).

Comment: A very concise answer , thank you sir !

Comment: `gcc -fomit-frame-pointer` has been the default on x86-64 (with optimization enabled) forever, and on 32-bit x86 for well over a decade.  Same for MSVC, it also doesn't waste EBP/RBP as a frame pointer.  https://godbolt.org/z/bE4c5Wv7h ;  Executable formats like ELF (on Linux) include stack-unwind metadata (`.eh_frame` tables based on program-counter addresses of where the stack-pointer changes, created from `.cfi` directives), making it unnecessary to have a linked list of EBP/RBP frame pointers.  Like Erik pointed out, static information instead of dynamic.

Comment: Some older 32-bit x86 systems may have needed EBP as a frame pointer for C++ exceptions to work, or for backtraces in debuggers.  `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is still sometimes useful for profiling with performance counters (e.g. Linux `perf record -g ----call-graph fp` instead of `dwarf` (ELF metadata) or `lbr` (hardware last branch record)), making stack snapshots more efficient and reliable when collecting on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Over the decades, architectures evolved from being memory intensive to being more register intensive.

Originally, there was maybe one data register, an accumulator, and programmers and designers naturally thought to locate & store variables, parameters, return addresses, etc.. in main memory — where else would they go?

Many architectures were even created before universal recognition of the need for a call stack.

As architectures evolved, call stacks were introduced, as well as additional registers, but system architecture still had a strong bias toward use of memory for parameters, local variables, and return addresses.

As availability of fast registers and good compilers increased, architectures started choose use of registers over memory.  Instruction set architectures for MIPS & RISC V & ARM, for example, store the return address in a linkage register, and if you want to put it onto the stack, you have to write code for that.

With lots of fast registers available, it became clear that sharing registers between procedures/functions/methods was a real issue — even with lots of registers, they are effectively global resources, and sharing them among thousands of functions takes some architecture.

So, hardware registers became partitioned by software conventions for two very basic but different scenarios — short-term and long-term usage.  For short-term usage, we don't want to pay any overhead, just use the register with impunity.  For long-term usage, we are willing to pay some overhead at function entry/exit in order that those values are properly preserved for a longer duration.  This is the motivation for the set of registers called call-clobbered vs. call-preserved (also by the misleading terms caller-saves vs. callee-saves).

What you're looking at with that reference is an intermediate snapshot in this evolution — a time when parameters & return addresses are pushed onto the stack, frame pointers are used to help organize and access the stack and stack frames.

Times have moved on since then, so most architectures now mostly use registers for passing parameters rather than pushing (though x86/64 still uses memory for the return address), and alternative (static, i.e. low dynamic overhead) approaches to stack unwind (such as static tables) are being used over dynamic management of frame pointers.